# Predict function for logistic regression returning results for entire dataset not just training dataset

Tags: r, glm, predict

I ma having an issue where the predict function for my logistic regression model is returning predictions for the entire dataset instead of just the test data. My test data has 6,931 rows in it. Here is my model:

```
test_model <- glm(status2~grade +  verified  + term + income + revolRatio +totalAcc + totalRevLim + accOpen24 ,data=Loan_test,family="binomial")
```

and here is my predict function:

```
probabilities <- predict(test_model,newdata=Loan_test, type="response")
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

Ok here is what I changed it to using my training dataset which has ~ 27000 rows:

```
test_model <- glm(status2~grade +  verified  + term + income + revolRatio +totalAcc + totalRevLim + accOpen24 ,data=Loan_training,family="binomial")

probabilities <- predict(test_model,newdata=Loan_test, type="response")
```

but probabilities still contains 34000+ rows.

Comment: You built your model on what appears to be your test data. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Yes that is what I intended to do.

Comment: A [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help. Otherwise it's unclear what the other data is that you expect the model to be using, since you've both built the model and are now trying to predict based on the same dataset which is labeled as being a test set

Comment: How is this- this is my original mode built using the training dataset:

Comment: How is this- this is my original mode built using the training dataset:     ```Loantrain_Four <- glm(status2~grade +  verified  + term + income + revolRatio +totalAcc + totalRevLim + accOpen24 ,data=Loan_training,family="binomial")```

Comment: You can [edit] your question to contain code where it's easier to follow than in comments. but without any data no one else will be able to run it anyway. Take a look at the suggestions in the link I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to predict against a hold out data set, one should split the initial data into training and test data frames. Since the OP comments note that there were separate training and test data frames, we'll simply use the training data frame to build the model, and make predictions against the test data frame.

```
# use training data for model
test_model <- glm(status2~grade +  verified  + term + income + revolRatio +totalAcc + totalRevLim + accOpen24 ,
                  data=Loan_training,family="binomial")

#make predictions using hold out data (test)
probabilities <- predict(test_model,newdata=Loan_test, type="response")
```

### A complete example: prediction with binomial regression

Here is a complete working example using the South African Heart Disease data from the `ElemStatLearn`package that shows when we split a data frame into test and training, fit a binomial model with `glm()` and make predictions with the test and training data frames, the number of predictions is equal to the size of the data frame used in `predict()`.

```
library(ElemStatLearn)
data(SAheart)
set.seed(801248)
train = sample(1:dim(SAheart)[1],size=dim(SAheart)[1]*.6,replace=F)
trainSA = SAheart[train,]
nrow(trainSA)
testSA = SAheart[-train,]
nrow(testSA)
```

At this point we can see that there are differing numbers of rows in `trainSA` and `testSA`.

```
> nrow(trainSA)
[1] 277
> testSA = SAheart[-train,]
> nrow(testSA)
[1] 185
>
```

Next, we fit a binomial general linear model with `glm()`.

```
modFit <- glm(chd ~ age + alcohol + obesity + tobacco + typea + ldl,
            data=trainSA,
            family="binomial")
```

When we make predictions on both test and training data frames, we note that the lengths of the output vectors match the numbers of rows in the original data frames.

```
predicted_test <- predict(modFit,testSA)
length(predicted_test)
predicted_train <- predict(modFit,trainSA)
length(predicted_train)
```

...and the output:

```
> length(predicted_test)
[1] 185
> predicted_train <- predict(modFit,trainSA)
> length(predicted_train)
[1] 277
```

Finally, we demonstrate that differences in results of `predict()` by calculating the misclassification rate for each data frame.

```
missClass = function(values,prediction){sum(((prediction > 0.5)*1) != values)/length(values)}
# Classification errors on TrainSA
missClass(trainSA$chd,predicted_train)
# Classification Errors on TestSA
missClass(testSA$chd,predicted_test)
```

...and the output:

```
> missClass(trainSA$chd,predicted_train)
[1] 0.2924188
> # Classification Errors on TestSA
> missClass(testSA$chd,predicted_test)
[1] 0.2594595
>
```

**CONCLUSION:** Somehow the code in the original post is referencing the original data frame when input into `predict()`, but we can't see it because it does not include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok I have done that using my training dataset which has ~ 27000 rows in it like this..                                                                                                                        ```test_model <- glm(status2~grade +  verified  + term + income + revolRatio +totalAcc + totalRevLim + accOpen24 ,data=Loan_training,family="binomial")

probabilities <- predict(test_model,newdata=Loan_test, type="response")``` but I am still returning 34000+  values in probabilities

Comment: 6931 rows in my test dataframe.

Comment: @JimRyan - I can't reproduce your problem. `predict()` works as expected on test data frame, see my updated answer. Also, please post a minimal reproducible example of your code or we won't  be able to help you more definitively.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. The length of my probabilities ios what is should be 6931. But when I displayed probabilities is when it was displaying probabilities for the entire dataset.